# How is an intervocalic "g" pronounced in Andean Spanish?

Tags: phonology, pronunciation, spanish, phonotactics

It seems that at least in the Andes, a lot of people say e.g. [awa] for "agua"[agwa]. What's the phonological rule behind this? Is it really [w]? Why did this happen in the first place?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be intervocalic lenition?

Comment: Isn't it more like "g" becomes a [velar approximant/glide/semivowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velar_approximant)?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the sequence *gua* was frequently used for the /wa/ sounds in transcribing Andean languages where modern Quechua orthography would have use *w*.  @hippietrail Likely, but it, like *b* and *d*, is very weak when used intervocalically and certainly wouldn't be out of the realm of possibility to be elided entirely.

Comment: Yes I haven't been to the Andes region but there were certainly a range of elided consonants through Central America.

Comment: @hippietrail's comment holds for standard versions of Spanish, so if Andean Spanish really is [awa], it's only a small further step to lose the already glided [g].  That is, the transcription [agwa] is not accurate.

Comment: I wonder if phonological things in this question have something to do with those in `guard`/`ward` — both of the same origin, but the former with the French mediation.

Comment: Note that this only happens when followed by -üi-/-üe-/-ua-/-uo-/-u<cons> etc, not in words like *águila* or *agarrar*. With -o...- too certainly in some places, eg *egoista*.

Comment: @delete The door swings both ways. In French, the germanic cognates 'wa-' unlenited to 'ga-' when borrowed into Old French  'warra': -> guerre,  'ward' -> 'guard'. Similarly in Iberian Spanish, where arabic 'wada' -> guada' as in the river 'Guadalquivir'

Answer (score 1):

At least from my experience as a native speaker (of Chilean Spanish), I think it's a more *popular* thing to hear that, as an example, I recall the word for someone with a big belly is `guatón` (`guata` = belly), which, as it's used in more informal contexts, could be heard as `watón`, while it should be written `guatón`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the title line you speak of "intervocalic g", while you actually mean "g followed by u", which is different. Only the latter case bears a similarity to "w".

In all languages I know, speakers make a difference between *careful speech* and casual speech, and this I believe is the case hier: "aɣwa" is careful speech and "awa" is easygoing speech.

I would also keep in mind that for millions of people in Peru and Bolivia Spanish is just a second language, so I would not expect everybody's pronunciation to be fully academic.

Answer (score 1):

The pronunciation of ɣ and w are similar anatomically, as the rear part of the mouth rises, so agua [aɣwa] tends to become [awwa] by assimilation, and in loose speech this becomes [awa].